# Implementing Real-time AR Navigation with Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on a cutting-edge Android project that involves creating a real-time augmented reality (AR) navigation system using Kotlin. The goal is to overlay navigation instructions onto the live camera feed, guiding users to their destination within indoor spaces like museums or airports.

I've researched ARCore for handling the AR aspects and have a basic understanding of integrating it with the camera feed. I've also explored using navigation components for the routing part. However, I'm facing challenges in merging these two complex technologies seamlessly.

Has anyone worked on a similar project or can provide guidance on how to effectively combine ARCore with navigation components? Specifically, I'm interested in:

Synchronizing AR elements with real-world coordinates: How can I accurately place AR navigation markers in the user's environment and ensure they stay aligned with the correct path even as the user moves?

Integrating turn-by-turn navigation: What's the best approach to integrate turn-by-turn navigation instructions into the AR experience? Should I leverage the built-in audio instructions and convert them into visual cues?

Optimizing performance: AR and navigation are both resource-intensive. How can I ensure a smooth experience without overwhelming the device's resources?

Dealing with varying indoor environments: Indoor spaces can have intricate layouts and varying light conditions. How can I adapt the AR navigation to different environments effectively?

If anyone has insights, resources, or even code snippets to share, I'd greatly appreciate it. This project aims to push the boundaries of user navigation, and I'm excited to overcome these challenges. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Best to use Unity instead of android studio to build ur project. Google depreciated Sceneform which used to make ar development very easy but now they want us to use opengl library to do so. if you really still wanna use android there is an opensource fork called sceneform maintained.